# Is it risky to download a script with a http://goo.gl/ link?

Tags: security, viruses, malware

Following the advise of an answer in Ask Ubuntu, I downloaded and ran a script with a URL starting by http://goo.gl/

Is it risky to use such file? could it be a virus or something else?

If yes, what should I do?

**Some details:**
I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/129200/32413), and did

```
    wget -O amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run http://goo.gl/VGYWP
    chmod +x amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run 
    ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run --extract driver
```

Comment: `Is it risky to download a script with a "http://" link`? Well, it's the Internet, so it *is* possibly harmful. On the other hand, not everyone has malicious intentions.

Comment: right, but I usually check the address, at least with WOT https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/wot-safe-browsing-tool/ . That time I forget, so I worry

Comment: `curl -I http://goo.gl/VGYWP` shows `Location: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run`. Although the use of a URL shortener looks suspicious, it seems to be your expected link?

Comment: good news, I was expecting to run a script to install the ATI driver for my graphic card - so it sounds good. I install `curl` for next time ...

Comment: I guess it was about shortening the command, which is too long indeed. Nothing insecure nor risky and of course, not suspicious in that link/command. You can also check that link on any browser and see where does it send you to. WOT is a great advice but even WOT can't be noticed of all threats.

Comment: I've replaced the goo.gl URL with the real URL in that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just create this answer to mark that I get the answer to my question **in your answers and comments.**

To sum up:

- yes a http://goo.gl/something can be risky, especially if then you run the downloaded script.
- to know what is behind such link, 2 solutions :

  - `curl -I http://goo.gl/something`
    in my case:

    ```
    curl -I http://goo.gl/VGYWP
    Location: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run
    ```
  - or do not download with `wget` but with Firefox and open your eyes
    [image]
    [image]
- then you can evaluate the risk knowing the location of the file to be downloaded.

Thank you all for your quick answers and comments.

Answer (score 6):

Extremely risky.

First you need to find what the original link of the shortened link is.

To do that add a `+` to the end of the `goo.gl` link like this (do not follow the link straight, because there is no way to know where it leads from just the address):

http://goo.gl/VGYWP+

This shows us the stats of who has clicked on it, and where they are located (it collects extra information, not just "link shortening") and shows that the *real* link is:

http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run

and the command you should use on that step is:

```
wget -O amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run
```

This also shows that a lot of people are "copy and pasting" same outdated answers from certain sites, and some are not citing where they got the information from.

Answer (score 5):

http://goo.gl/ is a url shortener service. You aren't downloading a file from that link, but it is redirecting you to somewhere else. It would be useful if you let us know where is the link sending you to, in order to know what happened when you clicked that link.

There are risks involved in downloading files from the net but the majority of the downloaded files get into your computer without execution properties allowed, so you aren't in a risk until you run it.

If you already run it, you should add to your question what did you do, this way people will be able to give you a warning or a solution.

Good luck!

Comment: I added the script link in my question

Answer (score 3):

http://goo.gl/ is a URL shortener, that is it is creating short URLs that redirect you to other, usually longer, URLs. As it can be used to create a redirect to any URL out there a `goog.le` link it may point to malicious or otherwise unwanted software.

In general you should never run any code if you are not sure that you can trust the source you got in from.

Maybe you could show us the script you run so we could tell you it it did any harm.

Comment: I added the script link in my question